# Compile Only implmentation of external lib is still required in end app

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, groovy

I have an external library that wraps some implementations of a third party library that we want to make interchangeable when I bring the features the third party does in-house. This is then published to Maven via JFrog

I then implement this wrapped library into my SDK lib using `compileOnly` and then have runtime checks to see if the other wrapped lib is installed. This is also published to Maven via JFrog

Now when I build a sample app and pull my SDK lib from maven the `compileOnly` library is failing to resolve in my sample app. Any other way I can get around this?

gradle setup of each level

lib-wrapper/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation("com.thirdparty:thirdparty-lib:0.0.1")
}
```

my-lib/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly("com.libwrapper:wrappedlib:0.0.1")
}
```

end-user-app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation("com.my-lib:lib:1.0.0")
}
```

And then the error received in the end-user-app is
`Failed to resolve: "com.thirdparty:thirdparty-lib:0.0.1"`

Is there any other way to resolve this?